# Kendo grid custom navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, navigation, grid

Is possible override default behaviour after any key press or disable it?

I've added this command to grid declaration

```
....,
navigatable: true,
....
```

but i can allow only arrow navigation, and add them custom function. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-row-navigation-by-keyboard there your scenario is not supported out of the box.
You can capture the keydown event and there implement your custom logic.

```
$(function () {
    var arrows = [38, 40];
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                grid.select($("#rowSelection_active_cell").closest("tr"));
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: hi, i found this solution, but not works for me ...

i've added this code to ready function after grid declaration, and after press the button nothing happened :/

Comment: i have one more question .. is possible deactivate focusing on grid header cells?

Comment: It's possible but a different approach is requiered. You need to decorate with a class the fields that you want to be navigable, and then implement the keydown event. Please read this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/skip-read-only-fields-when-using-keyboard-navigation-on-navigatable-grid-in-batch-edit-mode